comparing textformfield controller value to firestore record field
I am trying to compare textform controller value to record field in firestore it is the same value but it gives me false this is my code :
user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where('email', isEqualTo: "${emailController.text}")
                .where('password', isEqualTo: "${passwordController.text}")
                .where("status", isEqualTo: "1")
                .get();
if (user != null && user.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  if (user.docs[0].data()['roleid'] == "user") {
    prefs!.setString('role', "user");
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return CustomBottomAppBar();
      },
    ));
  } else if (user.docs[0].data()['roleid'] ==
      "admin") {
    prefs!.setString('role', "admin");

    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Adminbottomappbar();
      },
    ));
  } else if (user.docs[0].data()['roleid'] ==
      "super") {
    prefs!.setString('role', "super");

    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return SupervisorBottomAppBar();
      },
    ));
  }
}

my email and password controller
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

